# Unable to write into variable (ASM)

Tags: assembly, mov

I'm trying to learn Assembler and following a tutorial, and the first examples worked perfectly. I know a bit of the basics, but I'm having problems with variables. Here's the code I'm trying to compile:

```
leftbr db "("
rightbr db ")"
input db

start:
mov ah,08
int 21h
mov input,al

output:
mov dl,leftbr
mov ah,02
int 21h
mov dl,key
int 21h
mov dl,rightbr
int 21h

exit:
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h
```

It crashes at "input db" saying "invalid argument". If I change it to "input db "" " then it crashes at "mov input,al" claiming "invalid operands". I changed it to the following and it now works.

```
start:
mov ah,08
int 21h
mov [input],al

output:
mov [leftbr], "("
mov [rightbr], ")"
mov dl,[leftbr]
mov ah,02
int 21h
mov dl,[input]
int 21h
mov dl,[rightbr]
int 21h

exit:
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h

leftbr db 0
rightbr db 0
input db 0
```

Comment: db specifies that one or more bytes should be reserved, so you do need something to specify what that byte is. you could use a number or a character, but you need something.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. But what about the other issue ? Invalid operand.

Comment: what about "input db 0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `mov input, al` tries to move al into the value defined by the line `input db 0`, e.g. the compiler translates it into `mov 0, al`. What you want to do, is move al to the *position* "input", so I guess (ASM coding was some time ago for me) `mov [input], al` or `mov byte ptr:[input], al` would work better.

Edit: this is what displays "(a)" for me. Running CrunchBang Linux/Wine/FASM for windows.

```
format MZ
org 0x100

jmp start
leftbr db "(", 0
rightbr db ")"
input db "a"

start:
xor ax,ax
mov ah,08
;int 21h ; commenting this line because wine doesn't seem to like it
;mov [input],al

output:
mov dl,byte [leftbr]
mov ah,02
int 21h
mov ah,02 ; not sure if ah gets modified, probably not
mov dl,[input]
int 21h
mov ah,02
mov dl,[rightbr]
int 21h

exit:
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h
```

Comment: +1 but you don't need to cast input to byte because it's already. mov [input],al should work fine.

Comment: ah, i see. i guess it won't hurt though :)

Comment: Doesn't work. It compiles, but the program doesn't properly execute. It doesn't wait for input and it just prints out some random characters.

Comment: @andrew: what kind of compiler are you using? NASM, FASM, ..? Also, are you working under WinXP or something else? Apparently the INT 21h isn't working, because it should halt and wait for at least a keypress...

Comment: Running Linux+FASM+wine now. Move the definitions of leftbr, rightbr and everything else to the end of your code. If you keep it at the start, FASM will compile it at that very spot. The DOS VM will then start execution at "leftbr", which contains the value "(" which translates into bogus ASM code. Is this making any sense?

You could also do:
jmp _skip_data
<data defs here>
_skip_data:

Comment: I've did that (move the data towards the end). The only difference is that it now waits for input, and prints 3 characters. Problem is they're not the right ones.

Comment: I've now changed every variable reference in the code to [name] and now it waits for input and prints " x ". What's happening with the paranthesis ?

Comment: For me, it doesn't work with INT 21h/AH=08 (I guess this is the problem of wine). Thy changing mov dl,leftbr to mov dl, [leftbr] (as you are interested in the byte *at the address of leftbr*, not the address of leftbr itself. Also for the other two mov dl, input/key and rightbr.

Comment: I did. It prints out " x ", instead of " x ".

Comment: Add the line "org 0x100" to the top of your file. That worked for me at least. It has something to do with the addressing. An EXE or COM (can't remember) gets loaded at a certain offset (0x100 in this case). If you do not specify this, FASM will think that your variables are somewhere else. In reality, these variables get loaded starting from 0x100 while your code is referencing them starting from 0x0 (that's why you add org 0x100). I haven't coding assembly in a long, long time, that's for sure...

Comment: If I put the variables at the end, it works without org 0x100. If I put them at the beginning it won't work (it will just display "( )") even with org 0x100.

Comment: Yes, of course, because you are putting in the value yourself. Imagine this: FASM thinks the origin is at 0x00 so the address of leftbr becomes (for example) 0x50. Then, at line "mov [leftbr], "("", you effectively write "mov [0x50], "("" and then read back from that very same address. You should be able to define your data without actively putting in the data, so put org 0x100 and leftbr db "(", leave out "mov [leftbr], "("".

Comment: I tried that, same outcome "( )". Doesn't ask for input. At the beginning of the code there is org 0x100, the variables with their appropriate initialization ( "(" and ")" ) and same [] everywhere else.